# Launching Android Activity from adb shell

Tags: android, android-activity, adb

I have an android application installed on my phone and i would like to launch one of the activities through the adb shell. Here is the manifest of the file:

**EDIT** I have also  posted the logcat info below all of the manifest code and adb commands. It is throwing a NullPointerException.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2010100" android:versionName="2.1.1" package="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard.QuadrantStandardApplication">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".QuadrantStandardLauncherActivity" android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".QuadrantStandardActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.BenchmarkExecutionActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:noHistory="true" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.score.BenchmarkScoreActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.browser.DeviceVendorListActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.browser.DeviceListActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.browser.DeviceStatsActivity" />
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.sysinfo.SystemInfoActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
</manifest>
```

I tried launching the QuadrantStandardActivity using the command:

```
adb shell am start -n com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard/.QuadrantStandardActivity
```

and it worked. But when I tried to connect to another activity it failed. The command I used was:

```
adb shell am start -n com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard/com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.BenchmarkExecutionActivity
```

Logcat Info:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(11973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime(11973): java.lang.NullPointerException

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.core.C.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.A.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.BenchmarkExecutionActivity.h(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.r.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.r.a(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.r.apply(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.util.r.run(Unknown Source)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5074)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

E/AndroidRuntime(11973):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(  739):   Force finishing activity com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard/com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.BenchmarkExecutionActivity

W/ActivityManager(  739):   Force finishing activity com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard/.QuadrantStandardActivity

W/ActivityManager(  739): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{413150d0 u0 com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard/com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.runner.BenchmarkExecutionActivity}

I/ActivityManager(  739): Process com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard (pid 11973) has died.
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

when start the BenchmarkExecutionActivity throws a NullPointerException,check the code why throws the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> .BenchmarkExecutionActivity

should be in

> com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard

package. either change your package name in the first line of manifest from

```
package="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard"
```

to

```
package="com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui"
```

or put that activity inside

> com.aurorasoftworks.quadrant.ui.standard

package.